# Create Django token-based Authentication

Tags: python, django, web-services, authentication, oauth

I have my authentication service on django. I want to role it as a web-service to give other website a token and authenticate users with the token.
This is my scenario:

1. users visit external website and try to login
2. when hit the login button that website redirect user to my site to use username and password for login
3. When successfully logged in users will redirect to external website with a token
4. And every time that website send me that token, I recognize that user and pass some data to external website
   I'm try to use REST-Framework authentication but it is too complicated Please help me.

Comment: I would take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023762/token-based-authentication-in-django