# Token Based Authentication in latest Django

Tags: python, django, django-middleware

I'm trying to solve problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023762/token-based-authentication-in-django) but code provided in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5023911/6578528) not works for latest django==2.2

I have tried to port this code but failed with that

**settings.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE = ['polls.mymiddleware.CookieMiddleware',
```

**mysite/polls/authbackend.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend, UserModel


class Backend(RemoteUserBackend):
    def authenticate(**credentials):
        """We could authenticate the token by checking with OpenAM
        Server.  We don't do that here, instead we trust the middleware to do it.
        """
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(username=credentials['remote_user'])
            print('__user exists')
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            user = UserModel.objects.create(username=credentials['remote_user'])
            print('__user not exists')
        # Here is a good place to map roles to Django Group instances or other features.
        return user
```

**mysite/polls/mymiddleware.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, ImproperlyConfigured


class CookieMiddleware(object):
    """Authentication Middleware for OpenAM using a cookie with a token.
    Backend will get user.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured()
        if "thecookiename" not in request.COOKIES:
            return
        # token = request.COOKIES["thecookiename"]
        # REST request to OpenAM server for user attributes.
        # token, attribute, role = identity_manager.get_attributes(token)
        # user = authenticate(remote_user=attribute['uid'][0])
        user = authenticate(remote_user=1)  # simplified for test
        request.user = user
        login(request, user)
```

**result of that:**

```
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\mysite\mysite\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Update 1: fixed issue above, thanks to @Daniel_Rossman for that:

> need to put your middleware after the SessionMiddleware in your MIDDLEWARE settings.

but got now new problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 93, in __call__
    response = self.process_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\mysite\polls\mymiddleware.py", line 22, in process_request
    login(request, user, backend='polls.mymiddleware.CookieMiddleware')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 126, in login
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
[25/Apr/2019 12:40:07] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64298
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit yor middleware from `MiddlewareMixin` like this

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class CookieMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """Authentication Middleware for OpenAM using a cookie with a token.
    Backend will get user.
    """
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, 'user'):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured()
        if "thecookiename" not in request.COOKIES:
            return
        # token = request.COOKIES["thecookiename"]
        # REST request to OpenAM server for user attributes.
        # token, attribute, role = identity_manager.get_attributes(token)
        # user = authenticate(remote_user=attribute['uid'][0])
        user = authenticate(remote_user=1)  # simplified for test
        request.user = user
        login(request, user)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but new err occured:
\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 99, in login
    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'session'

could you help with that please?

Comment: You need to put your middleware after the SessionMiddleware in your MIDDLEWARE settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks a lot mate, this helped me but new problem occurred:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\mysite\polls\mymiddleware.py", line 22, in process_request
    login(request, user, backend='polls.mymiddleware.CookieMiddleware')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\my_scripts\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 126, in login
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
[25/Apr/2019 12:40:07] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64298